# How to calculate $2 ^ {-1} \pmod{10}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I want to know how to compute the inverse of a number when the module is composite and the number is not coprime.

Can anyone give me the options with an example of how to compute with $2 ^ {-1} \pmod{10}$?

Is there a way to do factorisation or some similar technique that ends with the same result like: $1/9  \pmod{10} = 1/3 \times 1/3  \pmod{10}$ and because 3 is comprime of 10 then is possible?

Thanks

Comment: It does not exist, so it cannot be computed.

Comment: @hardmath what options do I have then?

Comment: @TimberGray `what options do I have` Options to do *what*? If this is not the actual problem you are trying to solve, then you are on the wrong path, so better post the original problem. Otherwise the only answer to the question as posted is "*not possible*".

Comment: I suspect you asked how to do this because you wanted it to help with some other ptoblem.  If so, then going back to that *moyivation* would give Readers a chance to provide options.

Answer (score 6):

There is no answer.  You would be looking for what to multiply $2$ by to get $1$.  Just like in the integers, there is no such number.  The integers modulo $10$ form a ring (with zero divisors) and there is no guarantee you can divide in one of those.

Comment: Is there a way to do factorisation or some similar technique that ends with the same result like: $1/9  \pmod{10} = 1/3 \times 1/3  \pmod{10}$ and because 3 is comprime of 10 then is possible?

Comment: @TimberGray A simple way to see that is if $z$ is an integer such that $2z=1$ (mod 10) then $2z = 1+10k$ for some integer $k$, and multiplying both sides by 5 gives $10z = 5 + 50k$, which says $5$ is a multiple of $10$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Though if $w$ is a number such that $3w = 1$ (mod 10) then indeed $9w^2 =(3w)(3w)= 1$ (mod 10). So if you want to think of $w$ as a kind of $3^{-1}$, then you can also think of $w^2$ as a kind of $9^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes, as long as the $a$ is coprime to the modulus you can solve $ab=1$ and consider $b$ the inverse of $a$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that since $\gcd(10,2)=2$ by [**Bezout's identity**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BezoutsIdentity.html) for any $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$

$$a\cdot 10+b\cdot 2 \equiv 0 \pmod 2$$

then we can't find $a,b$ such that

$$a\cdot 10+b\cdot 2 = 1$$

and therefore $2$ is not invertible $\pmod{10}$.

More in general the modular equation

$$x\cdot n \equiv 1 \pmod m$$

has solution if and only if $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Here a general fact and a possibly useful idea to find quickly a multiplicative inverse.

Let's $m$ denote the module and $x,y$ integers. Note that

$$x\cdot y \equiv 1 \mod m \Leftrightarrow x\cdot y - 1 = k\cdot m \Leftrightarrow x\cdot y - k\cdot m = 1 \Leftrightarrow (x,m) = (y,m) = 1$$

So, **in your example that's not the case**.

Concerning how to find the inverse note that **provided that** $x$ and $m$ are coprime according to [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) you have
$$x^{\varphi(m)} \equiv 1 \mod m \Rightarrow x^{-1}\equiv x^{\varphi(m)-1} \mod m$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you could some $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ such that $2^{-1} = x\pmod{10}$, or equivalently (multiplying both sides by $2$): $1 = 2x \pmod{10}$. Multiplying both sides by $5$ gives $5 = 10x = 0 \pmod{10}$ which is a contradiction.

So no such $x$ exists.